# why mode isn't enabled?

Tags: emacs, dot-emacs

I've got an emacs configuration file `whatever.el` :

```
(abbrev-mode +1)
(provide 'whatever)
```

and in my `init.el` :

```
(require 'whatever)
```

but when i start emacs, `abbrev-mode` isn't enabled. why ?

thank you

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen `+` used like that, but I see it's valid (if redundant :)

Comment: i learned it reading the code from http://github.com/bbatsov/prelude i find it very readable activating with `+1` and desactivating with `-1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from http://emacswiki.org/emacs/AbbrevMode:

> You can also put the following in your ~/.emacs file if you want it
>   always on:
>
> ```
> (setq default-abbrev-mode t)
> ```
>
> If you only want it on in text and derived modes, you could do
>   something like this:
>
> ```
> (add-hook 'text-mode-hook (lambda () (abbrev-mode 1)))
> ```
>
> For multiple modes, use something like the following:
>
> ```
> (dolist (hook '(erc-mode-hook
>                 emacs-lisp-mode-hook
>                 text-mode-hook))
>   (add-hook hook (lambda () (abbrev-mode 1))))
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Abbrev-mode is enabled per-buffer.

One way is to create a hook function that you could add to the major mode hooks you will want to use it in.

For example:

```
(defun my-enable-abbrev-mode ()
  (abbrev-mode 1))
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'my-enable-abbrev-hook)
(add-hook 'java-mode-hook 'my-enable-abbrev-hook)
```

Another approach is to use `change-major-mode-hook`.

Answer (score 1):

While others explained how to get what you presumably want, I'll just point out that w.r.t to your actual question ("Why?"), the reason is simple: abbrev-mode is a buffer-local minor-mode, so when you run (abbrev-mode +1) at startup it will just enable abbrev-mode in the buffer that happens to be current during evaluation of the `~/.emacs` (typically *scratch*) but not in subsequent buffers.